# Objects do not get added to my NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to display a list of peoples in an `UITableView` (I write the name in the `ViewController` and display them as a list in the `UITableViewController`). 
I just need to stock up the data. But my code add just one object in the `NSMutableArray`. 
Is it because I use a singleton in my class "Customers"?
This is my code so far:

### Customers.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Customers : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    float age;
}


- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aname age:(float)aage ;

- (NSString*) name;
- (float) age;

- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName;
- (void) setAge:(float) newAge;

+(Customers*)instance;

@end
```

### Customers.m

```
#import "Customers.h"

@implementation Customers

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aname age:(float)aage {
    if ((self = [super init]))

    {
        self.name = aname;
        age = aage;
    }
    return self;

}

- (NSString*) name{
    return name;
}
- (float) age{
    return age;
}

- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName
{
    name = newName;
}
- (void) setAge:(float) newAge{
    age = newAge;
}

+(Customers*)instance{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static Customers *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithName:@"jean" age:24];
    });
    return sharedInstance;

}
@end
```

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Customers;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ageLabel;
- (IBAction)goToTableView:(id)sender;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Customers.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)goToTableView:(id)sender {
    [[Customers instance] setName:_nameLabel.text];    
}
@end
```

### TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Customers;

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
{
        NSMutableArray *peopleListe;

}
@end
```

### TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Customers.h"


@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Customers *koko = [[Customers alloc ] initWithName:[[Customers instance]name] age:[[Customers instance]age]];
    peopleListe = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
    [peopleListe addObject: koko];
    NSLog(@"%@",peopleListe);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return peopleListe.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];
    Customers *list = [peopleListe objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = list.name;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Thank you  for your help in advance.

Comment: You only have one `addObject:` call in this code, what exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: Because everytime I go to the UITableViewController I want to create a new object and add it in the Array. (I can go back to the ViewController and want to add an new data in the array by going to the UITableViewController)

Comment: The code example for this question is too long. It should be narrowed to something smaller that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want to add an object every time the controller gets loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Customers *koko = [[Customers alloc ] initWithName:[[Customers instance] name]
                                                   age:[[Customers instance] age]];

    peopleListe = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
    [peopleListe addObject: koko];
    NSLog(@"%@",peopleListe);
}
```

I see multiple problems with this:

1. I'm not sure `viewDidLoad` is the correct method to embed this in, i don't think it is guaranteed to get called if the view is already in memory. (I don't have any ios experience, so I'm not sure.) It might even be that your controller gets removed and created from scratch every time you use it.
2. You replace your whole list when you allocate peopleList. You should check for its existence and only allocate it if it does not exist yet. (Obj-C initializes instance variables as `nil`, so a simple check is enough.)

Apart from that, you seem to mix controller and model code. If you have the time you should look into moving the array into the model and out of the controller code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I used - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated, erased     peopleListe = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];

and still it doesn't work